# Error while converting varchar to datatype int in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have column `AccountNo` (`varchar(50)`). When I try to search data using `AccountNo` as filter then I get a error msg as below

[image]

my dataTable structure is as below:

[image]

and my code that gave me error is

```
SELECT 
   Date, particular,
   flag_voucherType +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,C.billNo) AS [VoucherNo.],
   Debit, Credit, Narration 
FROM 
    ((SELECT 
         Particular, flag_voucherType,accountNo,companyId 
      FROM  
         tblInsertParticularRecord 
      WHERE 
         Credit = 0 
         AND flag = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @accountNum) 
         AND companyId = @companyId) AS A  
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT  
        CONVERT(Decimal,0) AS Debit, Debit AS Credit, accountNo,companyId, billNo 
     FROM tblInsertParticularRecord 
     WHERE 
        flag1 = 0 
        AND flag = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @accountNum) 
        AND companyId = @companyId) AS B ON A.accountNo = B.accountNo AND A.companyId = B.companyId)
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
          Date, billNo, companyId, Narration 
      FROM tblJournalDateNarrationDetails) AS C ON (B.billNo = C.billNo AND B.CompanyId = C.companyId)
```

Comment: which value has @companyId? must be integer. and @accountNum ?

Comment: It seems you have one more table as tblJournalDateNarrationDetails, pls share schema of that table also.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: Have you tried running your script that you pasted? The problem may not be on those select statements. Could be a trigger or on other part of your stored procedure.

Comment: yes i tried to execute it many times,

Comment: companyId is int and accountNum is varchar @user3401335

Comment: Please post the DDL of tblJournalDateNarrationDetails table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you care reading the error? YOU maerked out a lof of the string but - guess what - from he stuff you did not mark out it already is clear that the string is not an int. "-1-00-1" at the end is not something you can convert o a string. Back to the drawing board with requirements.

EIther your accounts are a coded string (with "-" mixed in), in which case you need some serious string manipulation to remove the surplus symbols before calling the convert - or - well - someone really did not bother to check whether account numbers are strings at all. You an not throw that type of string at a convert function and expect it to magically work.

Most likely the number is a code - something that has a business meaning but for the program is a series of characters - and no, you then should no even try to convert it into a number, your mistake. Store them as strings.